# Require React-Native conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a generic element which returns `div` in the web and `View` in React-Native.
Currently, it looks like this:

```
export const Element = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
    return <div {...rest}>{children}</div>
  } 
  try {
    const View  = require('react-native').View;
    return <View {...rest}>{children}</View>
  } catch (e) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

I use try-catch because I get this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native'

How can I conditionally require React-Native without the need for try-catch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try import react-native outside function like

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
```

```
export const Element = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
    return <div {...rest}>{children}</div>
  } 
    return <View {...rest}>{children}</View>
};
```

may be help you.